New MacBook .. Old Tabs
This may be a silly question but is it possible to restore tabs that were open on my old macbook to the new one ?
My old computer fully gave up and had to be sent to apple to be fixed . They did tell me it would wipe all info, which is fine. When I started using my new macbook I installed and opened Chrome and signed in but I can't find a way to restore the old tabs that were open on the other macbook .

Why would you want to restore the tabs?

Since it's a fresh installation and Chrome considers it a different device, you'll need to look in "History" → "Tabs from other devices" chrome://history/syncedTabs.
(It seems that the latest Chrome also has a "Tab groups" button in the bookmarks toolbar, but that only shows grouped tabs, not the ungrouped ones.)
If tabs from the old device aren't there, then they likely weren't synced and you'd need to dig through "Chrome history" to find what might have been visited.
